# delete line and the following one if condition met

Tags: bash, grep

I have this kind of file and I use bash:

```
&ACLB032-06|Bos taurus|COI-5P|HM102290
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTATTCTATATCAACACTTATTC--------
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|atp6
ATGAACGAAAATTTATTTACCTCTTTTACCAATTCTAGAGTTTGCAGTAGCTATAATCCAAGCCTATGTATTCACTCTCCTAGTCAGCCTATATCTGCATGACAACACA
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|D-loop
AACACTATTAATATAGTTCCATAAATACAAAGCGCTTTCAATACTCAATTTAGCACTCCAAACAAAGTCAATATATAAACGCAGGCCCCCCCCCCC
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|COII
ATGGCATATCCCATACAACTAGGATTCCAAGCGGGTCAAACCACAGTTTCATACCCATTGTCCTTGAGTTAGTCCCACTAAAGTACTTTGAAAAATGATCTGCGTCAA
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|COI-5P|HQ184039
CATAAAGATATTGGTACCCTTTATCTAAAAAGTCTTCAGCTGATTAGCAACACTTCATGGAGGT
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|CYTB
ATGACTAACATTCGAAAGTCCCACCCACTACCTAGTGCTAATACCAACGGCCGGCACAGTCGAAAACAAATTACTAAAATGA
```

The file might contains a million of lines
I want to keep only lines containing the string "COI-5P" as well as their following lines, which would result in this

```
&ACLB032-06|Bos taurus|COI-5P|HM102290
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTATTCTATATCAACACTTATTC--------
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|COI-5P|HQ184039
CATAAAGATATTGGTACCCTTTATCTAAAAAGTCTTCAGCTGATTAGCAACACTTCATGGAGGT
```

But I have trouble to find solution.
Can you help me please?

Comment: Is that really what your file look like? Are you sure it doesn't have a `>` at the beginning of the ID line? Isn't it fasta?

Answer (score 4):

You could try (assuming GNU grep):

```
grep -A1 --no-group-separator 'COI-5P' file
```

The `grep` man page says:

> ### Context Line Control
>
> #### `-A` *NUM*, `--after-context=`*NUM*
>
> Print *NUM* lines of trailing context after matching  lines.   Places  a  line  containing 
>   a  group
>              separator  (`--`) between contiguous groups of matches.  With the `-o` or `--only-matching` option, this
>              has no effect and a warning is given.
>
> #### `--no-group-separator`
>
> Use empty string as a group separator.

Tests:

```
$ cat file
&ACLB032-06|Bos taurus|COI-5P|HM102290
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTATTCTATATCAACACTTATTC--------
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|atp6
ATGAACGAAAATTTATTTACCTCTTTTACCAATTCTAGAGTTTGCAGTAGCTATAATCCAAGCCTATGTATTCACTCTCCTAGTCAGCCTATATCTGCATGACAACACA
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|D-loop
AACACTATTAATATAGTTCCATAAATACAAAGCGCTTTCAATACTCAATTTAGCACTCCAAACAAAGTCAATATATAAACGCAGGCCCCCCCCCCC
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|COII
ATGGCATATCCCATACAACTAGGATTCCAAGCGGGTCAAACCACAGTTTCATACCCATTGTCCTTGAGTTAGTCCCACTAAAGTACTTTGAAAAATGATCTGCGTCAA
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|COI-5P|HQ184039
CATAAAGATATTGGTACCCTTTATCTAAAAAGTCTTCAGCTGATTAGCAACACTTCATGGAGGT
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|CYTB
ATGACTAACATTCGAAAGTCCCACCCACTACCTAGTGCTAATACCAACGGCCGGCACAGTCGAAAACAAATTACTAAAATGA

$ grep -A1 --no-group-separator 'COI-5P' file
&ACLB032-06|Bos taurus|COI-5P|HM102290
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNCTATTCTATATCAACACTTATTC-----------
&CYTC426-12|Bos taurus|COI-5P|HQ184039
CATAAAGATATTGGTACCCTTTATCTAAAAAGTCTTCAGCTGATTAGCAACACTTCATGGAGGT
```

Comment: it works indeed but some parasites "-" appear. 
Thx for your help!

Comment: @AdrienAndre See update with fixed some parasites "--".

Comment: thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with this code :

```
awk '/COI-5P/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]}; NR in nr' oldfile > newfile
```

where

- `/COI-5P/{nr[NR]; nr[NR+1]}` record matching line and following
- `NR in nr` select and implicitly print recorded lines.

Comment: You don't even need to record all the line numbers in an array, you could use a simple counter variable: `awk /COI-5P/{i=2};i-->0'`